# Hide Form After Submission

Tags: jquery

I'm using this [form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#html)

But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do much DOM manipulation after the form has been submitted.

```
$('.save-form').each(function() {
    $(this).ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {      
            //
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried `$(this).find('div').hide();` but to no avail.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="save-form">
    <!-- inputs are here -->
    <div>I want to hide this as well as the parent, "save-form".</div>
</form>
<form method="post" class="save-form">
    <!-- inputs are here -->
    <div>I want to hide this as well as the parent, "save-form".</div>
</form>
<form method="post" class="save-form">
    <!-- inputs are here -->
    <div>I want to hide this as well as the parent, "save-form".</div>
</form>
```

Yes, I have more than one instance of "save-form"

Comment: You could just use $(".save-form") rather than the longhand selector you've used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*each* accepts two params. Use them.

```
$('[class=save-form]').each(function(index, form) {
    $(this).ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {      
            //
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(form).find('div').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In this case `form` will be a DOM node, not a jQuery object. You will need to do `$(form).hide();`. But +1 for remembering that extra argument which I always forget!

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
$('[class=save-form]').each(function() {
    $(this).ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {      
            //
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('[class=save-form]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Notice that it will hide what is in the wrapped set `$('[class=save-form]')`. You may want to adjust your selector as per your needs.

---

By the way, you can use:

```
$('.save-form')
```

Instead of:

```
$('[class=save-form]')
```

Comment: That will hide all elements that match `[class=save-form]` when one successfully completes.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Yeah was writing that (before your comment seen), updated.

Comment: Oops, I asked my question wrong. I have updated my post to include what I'm trying to hide.

Comment: @Aaron:For that you can use `$('.save-form > div').hide();` for immediate div children or `$('.save-form div').hide();` for divs at any depth. Notice that as you said this will hide divs only.

Comment: @Aaron: You want to hide all forms and everything inside them right ?

Comment: @Sarfraz I'm just trying to hide the div and form that was submitted, none of the other ones. Could it be an issue with this plug-in?

Answer (score 2):

If you store a reference to `this` before calling `ajaxForm` you will be able to use that inside the event handlers:

```
$('[class=save-form]').each(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    $(this).ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {      
            //
        },
        success: function(data) {
            form.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It will still hide all forms since it is inside `each`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer but could you wrap it around a div and hide that? Seems easiest way.